# How to save dataSource renderRow values into class variable in React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am new to React Native and trying to fetching student records using "fetch" method in React Native and saving the response (my response will look like)

```
   {"student":[{"student_id":"1","student_name":"JHON","student_class_id":"22"},
   {"student_id":"2","student_name":"BONY","student_class_id":"22"}],"error":false})
```

to dataSource as follows

```
   .then((responseJson) => {
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.setState({
           dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.student)
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
      });
    })
```

And rendering it like

```
 getClassId(){
    // here I want to access rowData.student_class_id
 }

 render() {

    return(
     ....
     ....
 <View style={styles.card}>
          <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={
                (rowData) =>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>{rowData.student_id}</Text>

                  <Text style={styles.text}>{rowData.student_name}</Text> 
                </View>
              }
          />
        </View> 
  );
}
```

And from the response we can see the "student_class_id" field. I don't want to show it in the text view. But I want to access this value out side  of this render method. That is some where in the other method of same class.

I am not getting any feasible solution. Please guide me to achieve it. Any  suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

1. Please don't use ListView, use FlatList or SectionList instead. Check this [blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html) for more info
2. You can access `this.state.dataSource` in `getClassId`. You can map over the dataSource and get the ids you need

Hope this helps